# A good and valid example of Common Collector BJT

Tags: bjt, ltspice, npn, bias, common-collector

I am analyzing a common collector BJT as an amplifier using LTSpice. I have made the following circuit and I am not getting the exact characteristics which I should have got.

[image]

Is there something wrong in this circuit? It is clear that the polarity of the batteries is correct and we have to vary them to obtain the characteristics. Please help!!

Comment: Your schematic is difficult to "decode" as it does not meet the standard conventions (see: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics/28255#28255), here's an example of how you would want your circuit to look like: https://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/03101.png

Comment: Yes there's something wrong with the circuit as the voltage on the base is **lower** than the voltage on the emitter and since this an NPN the BE junction is **reverse biased**. I suggest starting with re-drawing the circuit as from the picture I mentioned above and take it from there.

Comment: Try drawing it like this: https://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/03101.png

Comment: Describe the characteristics that you have to extract.

Comment: This figure which you have given link to, is not a Common Collector.

Comment: Try drawing the circuit using the tool provided by stack exchange. Also, can you tell us what's "wrong" in the output? that will reduce the "guessing" time for us.